# In MSA architecture, I wonder about auth domain(server)'s database schema

Tags: authentication, architecture

I try to make MSA architecture these days.

When I make auth domain(server), I wonder about auth domain's database schema.

At the first time when I thought, if I put information about id and password in auth database, it will be great.

But, some problem came up.

There are so many domains use this auth server. But, every server need separate id and password that only use in their service.

In this case, where I have to save id and password schema?

In auth domain(server)? or somewhere separate service domain server?

Thanks.

I try to make every service domain server got their own id and password...